# How to show a JSON list without repeat Angular JS

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm using Angular JS to show a list of items from a JSON get request.

I'm able to retreive the items, but i'm not able to show them in the right order without repeating.

My JSON file looks like :

```
[
{
"id":"32",
"competiton":"série1",
"game":"A- B"
},
{
"id":"33",
"competiton":"série1",
"game":"C - D"
}
]
```

here is my code to retrieve the items :

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://myserver.com/matches?date=2015-05-18")
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.matches = response;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            setName($scope.matches, i);
        }
    });

var setName = function (matches, index) {
    $http.get("http://myserver.com/ofc/competitions/" + matches[index].idCompetition)
        .success(function (response) {
            matches[index].competition = response.name;
             $scope.competitions[index] = response.name;
        });
}
});
```

and here is how i'm showing them :

```
<div ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<div class="list">


   <div class="item item-divider" ng-repeat="m in matches">
    {{ m.competition}}
  </div>
  <a class="item" href="#" ng-repeat="m in matches">
    {{ m.game }}
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Items are showig like :

Série A

Série A

A - B

C - D

I want to show them like :

Série A

A - B

C - D
.... etc

Comment: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

Comment: To show all the competetions and all the teams

Comment: I feel like your json isn't good for your use case. You should maybe gather your data by competitions.

Comment: I agree with @Okazari.

Answer (score 1):

Use "unique":

```
<div class="item item-divider" ng-repeat="m in matches | unique:'competition'">
    {{ m.competition}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Nice spot but i feel that there is a more deep miss-use behind this behaviour. Anyway this will do the work ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this is giving an error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: uniqueFilterProvider <- uniqueFilter`

Comment: AngularJS does not have a built-in unique filter. You may be look at this : http://angular-ui.github.io/ "Angular UI" so you can use unique filter :) .